# Can I manually specify a host for a gRPC server using Python?

Tags: python, server, localhost, grpc, grpc-python

I'm developing a gRPC application using Python and the basic `grpc` library as well as `proto`. In my client I can easily specify a port and host when creating a channel, but when creating a server like so `server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))` I can't find any way to specify a host. I can add ports to the server via `server.add_insecure_port(port info)`but am totally stumped on specifying a host. I've combed through the documentation [here](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/basics/) and [here](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/), and have looked through any relevant queries elsewhere, but I can't find a solution. The closest I can find is this `asyncio`/`grpclib` [library](https://grpclib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) that has this functionality, but I don't want to use this as the gRPC library seems perfect for my use case. Is there any way I can pass in a host?

Comment: `server.add_insecure_port()` accepts port as address like "localhost:9000" or "0.0.0.0:9000"

Comment: @Kris Does that mean the host is included in `add_insecure_port` as well?

Comment: Yes. As per my understanding it accepts a qualified address, not just a port.

Comment: You need to specify a server host on the client (host) because the two may be on different hosts. A server (running on a host) may want to specify which of its host's IP addresses or, commonly all interfaces (i.e. `[::]` which is I think an alias for `0.0.0.0`) it will use and @kris comment explains how to do this **but** the only way you can "specify a host for a server" is when you decide on which host you're going to deploy code (e.g. your server).